# i was trying to create django model and i got this error TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django

```
    gender_choices = models.CharField[('M', 'Male'), ('F','Female')]
    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices, max_length=1, default=None, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as

```
gender_choices = (('M', 'Male'), ('F','Female'))
gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices, max_length=1, default=None, null=True)
```

**Note :** The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set and second element is name.

Answer (score 0):

For the choices you should construct a simple list, not use `CharField`, so:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F','Female')]
    gender = models.CharField(
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
        max_length=1,
        default=None,
        null=True
    )
```